# ASP.NET Core Websockets on remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, websocket, deployment

I am trying to make some kind of messaging application and I want to utilize WebSocket. I found many tutorials on how to do it and I have made a working one which only works on localhost.

How can I deploy a WebSocket server? And how can I connect to it on the client side?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to look at [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr)

Comment: What prevented you from connecting to it from another computer when you tried it?

Comment: Michael Roy's suggestion is very good, and usually we may need to enable websocket (or install the websocket feature in windows server). You should provide more detaills if you faced some specific issue, then we can help you better.